# Boost / Python unix timestamps don't match

Tags: python, datetime, boost, epoch

Python 2.6:

```
import pytz
import time
import datetime
time.mktime(datetime.datetime(1990, 1, 1, tzinfo=pytz.utc).timetuple())
```

Result:

```
631148400.0
```

Boost 1.46:

```
auto a = boost::posix_time::ptime(boost::gregorian::date(1990, 1, 1));
auto b = boost::posix_time::ptime(boost::gregorian::date(1970, 1, 1)); // unix epoch
boost::posix_time::time_duration x = a - b;
std::cerr << x.total_seconds() << std::endl;
```

Result:

```
631152000
```

Difference is 3600 (1 hour). Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the example below I set my time zone to GMT-01:

```
>>> import datetime, time, pytz

>>> tz = pytz.FixedOffset(-60)
>>> dt = datetime.datetime(1990, 1, 1, tzinfo=pytz.utc)

>>> tm = dt.astimezone(tz).timetuple(); tm
time.struct_time(tm_year=1989, tm_mon=12, tm_mday=31, tm_hour=23, tm_min=0, tm_s
ec=0, tm_wday=6, tm_yday=365, tm_isdst=0)

>>> time.mktime(tm)
631152000.0
```

`mktime` takes a time tuple based on local time, so the UTC `datetime` object has to first be adjusted to local time.

Comment: Thanks, this works. `dateutil.tz.tzlocal()` can be used to get the local time zone (http://labix.org/python-dateutil).

Answer (score 0):

The second code uses local time, the first one uses UTC explicitly.

Comment: But it's a time difference shouldn't it be equal nevertheless?